# meaning of clap along

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In the song 'Happy' by Pharrell Williams the lyrics say: Clap along. What does it mean?

> Clap along if you feel like happiness is the truth,
>
> clap along if you know what happiness is to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clap" means to bring the hands together rapidly to produce a shard sound, also called applauding.

To clap along, especially with a song, means to repeatedly clap one's hands simultaneously with other people, and in time with the beat of the song.